# Julia Memory Allocation for Addition of Two Matrices in place

Tags: julia, lapack, blas, in-place

I'm curious why Julias implementation of matrix addition appears to make a copy. Heres an example:

```
foo1=rand(1000,1000)
foo2=rand(1000,1000)
foo3=rand(1000,1000)

julia> @time foo1=foo2+foo3;
  0.001719 seconds (9 allocations: 7.630 MB)
julia> sizeof(foo1)/10^6
8.0
```

The amount of memory allocated is roughly the same as the memory required by a matrix of these dimensions.

It looks like in order to process foo2+foo3 memory is allocated to store the result and then foo1 is assigned to it by reference.

Does this mean that for most linear algebra operations we need to call BLAS and LAPACK functions directly to do things in place?

Comment: `sizeof(foo1)/(1024*1024)` does in fact round to `7.630`.

Comment: It's worth noting that Eigen C++ library does not do this
http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicLazyEvaluation.html

Answer (score 15):

To understand what is going on here, let's consider what `foo1 = foo2 + foo3` actually does.

- First it evaluates `foo2 + foo3`. To do this it will allocate a *new* temporary array to hold the output
- Then it will bind the name `foo1` to this new temporary array, undoing all effort you put in to pre-allocate the output array.

In short, you see that memory usage is about that of the resultant array because the routine is indeed allocating new memory for an array of that size.

Here are some alternatives:

- write a loop
- use `broadcast!`
- We could try do do `copy!(foo1, foo2+foo3)` and then the array you pre-allocated will be filled, but it will still allocate the temporary (see below)
- The original version posted here

Here's some code for those 4 cases

```
julia> function with_loop!(foo1, foo2, foo3)
           for i in eachindex(foo2)
              foo1[i] = foo2[i] + foo3[i]
           end
       end

julia> function with_broadcast!(foo1, foo2, foo3)
           broadcast!(+, foo1, foo2, foo3)
       end

julia> function with_copy!(foo1, foo2, foo3)
           copy!(foo1, foo2+foo3)
       end

julia> function original(foo1, foo2, foo3)
           foo1 = foo2 + foo3
       end
```

Now let's time these functions

```
julia> for f in [:with_broadcast!, :with_loop!, :with_copy!, :original]
           @eval $f(foo1, foo2, foo3) # compile
           println("timing $f")
           @eval @time $f(foo1, foo2, foo3)
       end
timing with_broadcast!
  0.001787 seconds (5 allocations: 192 bytes)
timing with_loop!
  0.001783 seconds (4 allocations: 160 bytes)
timing with_copy!
  0.003604 seconds (9 allocations: 7.630 MB)
timing original
  0.002702 seconds (9 allocations: 7.630 MB, 97.91% gc time)
```

You can see that `with_loop!` and `broadcast!` do about the same and both are much faster and more efficient than the others. `with_copy!` and `original` are both slower and use more memory.

In general, to do inplace operations I'd recommend starting out by writing a loop

Comment: it looks like this is a pretty informative answer, perhaps the original poster could accept it?

Answer (score 2):

First, read @spencerlyon2's answer. Another approach is to use Dahua Lin's package `Devectorize.jl`. It defines the `@devec` macro which automates the translations of vector (array) expressions into looped code.

In this example we will define `with_devec!(foo1,foo2,foo3)` as follows,

```
julia> using Devectorize      # install with Pkg.add("Devectorize")

julia> with_devec!(foo1,foo2,foo3) = @devec foo1[:]=foo2+foo3
```

Running the benchmark achieves the 4 allocations results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `axpy!` function from the LinearAlgebra package.

```
using LinearAlgebra
```

```
julia> @time BLAS.axpy!(1., foo2, foo3)
  0.002187 seconds (4 allocations: 160 bytes)
```

Comment: This is a bad answer as for almost all cases, `foo1 .= foo2 .+ foo3` is more appropriate

Comment: More appropriate in what aspect? If you benchmark, the median runtime of axpy! is 1.2ms whereas your suggestion is 1.8ms.